# If statement to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

How to add if statement to associative array?

```
$menu = array(   ''                  => 'user_menu_general',
                '&b=avatar'         => 'user_menu_avatar',
                '&b=notifications'  => 'user_menu_notifications',
                '&b=social'         => 'user_menu_social',
                '&b=security'       => 'user_menu_security');
```

I only want to add `'&b=notifications'  => 'user_menu_notifications'` if `$value == 1`...

Comment: Write the if statement after the array definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$menu = array(   ''             => 'user_menu_general',
            '&b=avatar'         => 'user_menu_avatar',
            '&b=social'         => 'user_menu_social',
            '&b=security'       => 'user_menu_security');
if ($value == 0)
     $menu['&b=notifications']  = 'user_menu_notifications';
```

It is usually easier to add it to the array afterwards if the if statement value is met.